# Best type of indexing when there is LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT name, usage_guidance, total_used_num
FROM tags
WHERE
 ( name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
   usage_guidance LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') )
 AND name NOT IN ($in)
ORDER BY name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') DESC, name ASC
LIMIT 6
```

Which one is the best index?

- `tags(name,usage_guidance)`
- `tags(usage_guidance,name)`
- `tags(name)`
- `tags(usage_guidance)`

Or is there any better option?! You know, when `LIKE` comes in, I'm getting confused bout creating indexes. Because `LIKE %something` would never take any benefit of indexes. Also in query above I have both `AND`, `OR` and `IN` .. That's why I asked this question to know your opinion about it too.

---

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `usage_guidance` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `related` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `total_used_num` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date_time` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I'm trying to make a autocomplete suggestion query. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: @barmar, Using *full-text* isn't proper for what I'm looking for .. Because *full-text* doesn't support search-based-on-one-letter ..!

Comment: If you can't use FTS, then you're just out of luck. There's no way to index searches that start with `%`.

Comment: Maybe that's why SO doesn't use MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar ..! Oh really?! SO doesn't use MySQL?! Shit ...! I thought it does. Actually I'm trying to make a website similar to SO. Well what DB is it using?

Comment: SQL-Server: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/what-database-does-stackoverflow-use

Comment: Well @Barmar is right. FYI, postgresql can use indexes on these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, what you have here is a database killer

> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that
>   use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators. The index also can be
>   used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string
>   that does not start with a wildcard character.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html

So that means your LIKE query cannot use the index and then you have two likes connected with an OR. If that's not enough, you have thrown in a NOT IN comparison as well.

But fortunately, the second LIKE expression isn't so bad, it doesn't start with a wildcard. So your best hope is to create a composite index on `usage_guidance, name`

If you could post your SHOW CREATE TABLE and a few lines of sample data + the expected output, we might get an idea if there is a way to rewrite this query.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. Also please take a look at the update version of my question and tell me can I write that query better?

Comment: Judging by your update, your query probably will not benefit from a full text search which the duplicate points to. Edit the question to reflect that and I will cast a reopen vote.