# Mysql query seems to have crashed a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT email from sending
WHERE `subject` LIKE '%wildcard1%'
AND email  NOT In (SELECT email FROM sending where subject LIKE '%wildcard2%' );
```

Hi.
I ran this query in my phpmyadmin on a 160.000 entries table.
Since then, my database and website get stuck anytime i am trying to to access that certain table.
The size of the table seems pretty big, too ( 160 MB )

Any idea what the problem is?
I was just trying to find emails that received a campaign notification but have not been sent a second notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best type of indexing when there is LIKE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show if a index is on email and try this query:

```
SELECT s1.email FROM sending s1
WHERE s1.subject LIKE '%wildcard1%'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM sending s2 
    WHERE s2.email = s1.email 
    AND s2.`subject` LIKE '%wildcard2%');
```

Comment: Added index on email and ran just fine. Thank you!  :)