# How do I get the names of another table through ids in a specific field?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a **genre system** and would like to know how I can get "**names**" from one table through the **set of ids** in another **specific field**.

Let's suppose that this column refers to the ids of the genres to which this video belongs:

```
| genres
| 1,2,3    <--- This field for example.
| 5,9,10
```

And I still have the table of genres being something like this:

```
| genre_id | genre_title
| 1        | Comedy
| 2        | Romance
| 3        | School
```

I want to turn that field into something like this:

> Comedy, Romance, School

And I'm using a php code like this to get the information filtered by gender.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpw","$db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Falha ao ligar à Base de Dados: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$gender = $_GET['g'];
$getGender = "FIND_IN_SET('$gender',a_generos) = $gender";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tblAnimes WHERE $getGender") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($home = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "Name: " . $home['a_titulo'];
    echo "Publication date: " . $home['a_dia'];
    echo "Genres IDs (por agora): " . $home['a_generos']; //Get something like this (1,2,3) but i want this (Comedy, Romance, School)
}
?>
```

The main question is how do I turn it (1,2,3) into it (Comedy, Romance, School).

Comment: The best way would to be to refactor your table structure so that you are not storing comma separated value lists in a single field; much better is an M-to-N table relating the main tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41305027/267540

Comment: This link helps in that way, I did not understand