# Comparing and updating Arrays in mySQL records

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, beacon

**Scenario:**
I have multiple static receivers detecting mobile beacons and recording relative signal strength of each.  Each beacon pings 1/second, and I am using a rolling average to smooth out the variances in that reading over time.    I record that average reading every x seconds (15) locally, then post that array to an sql database every y seconds (300s, so an array of 20).

**My constraints are:**

- receivers can’t talk to each other locally
- I don’t want to post to the server for every signal each receiver receives (way too many records very quickly)
- I am writing in **python** and **mySql** because that’s what I know (noSQL may be a future implementation)
- I don’t control the server, so scheduling server-side processing
  is challenging (I think)
- arrays are of an indeterminate length (hence array instead of fields)

**My goal is** to reject the receiver that has the lower signal (i.e. is comparatively further away from the beacon) for each element of the posted array.

**My current approach is:**

- post a set to the database
- query that database for any sets from the same beacon (but different
  receivers) that intersect the time window of the posted set

  - expect up to 2 sets for each nearby receiver, so under 10 records would match the query
- pull those sets into a 2D array (correcting for offsets when the time
  windows aren’t exactly the same)
- zip(*lis) to transform that array
- find the minimum element in each row, write that as 1 and the rest as
  0
- zip(*lis) that back into the original form of the 2D array
- post the results back to a “winner” field in the database via update
  (this way we retain the original signal readings)

I recognize this exposes me to a problem where multiple receivers are posting at the same time and overwriting each others filtered array results.

I suspect there may be other problems with this approach, but I can’t figure out a better way.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41305027/267540 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41215681/267540