# Use MySQL IN condition in FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, clause

I have a query where I use a pretty intensive WHERE IN clause to get a list of ID's related to players.

```
SELECT p.name,
  0a.stat_value
FROM leaderheadsplayers p
LEFT JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
ON 0a.player_id    = p.player_id
AND 0a.stat_type   = 'kills'
WHERE p.player_id IN
  (SELECT player_id
  FROM
    (SELECT 0a.player_id
    FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
    WHERE 0a.stat_type = 'kills'
    ORDER BY 0a.stat_value DESC LIMIT 0,
      20
    ) 1a
  )
```

The problems is that I want to keep the order of these ID's from the IN clause in my final result by using a FIND_IN_SET without doing the intensive query from the IN clause again.
Something like this:

```
SELECT p.name,
  0a.stat_value
FROM leaderheadsplayers p
LEFT JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
ON 0a.player_id    = p.player_id
AND 0a.stat_type   = 'kills'
WHERE p.player_id IN
  (SELECT player_id
  FROM
    (SELECT 0a.player_id
    FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
    WHERE 0a.stat_type = 'kills'
    ORDER BY 0a.stat_value DESC LIMIT 0,
      20
    ) 1a
  )
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(p.player_id, result_from_in_clause)
```

This is my current output:

```
player_id | stat_value
3 | 304
5 | 507
4 | 208
```

This is what I want to get:

```
player_id | stat_value
5 | 507
3 | 304
4 | 208
```

Comment: Which order? the one you defined inside the subquery?

Comment: @Rovin Your recent edit left your question not readable.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: Show a) Sample data and b) expected output

Comment: Added more clarification.

Comment: When ever find_in_set comes up, I jump to the natural conclusion that your tables aren't normalized. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41215681/267540 http://stackoverflow.com/a/41305027/267540

Comment: I don't see why my tables aren't normalized. I'm not doing any crazy stuff like saving a delimited list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `order by` should be able able to do it:

```
SELECT p.name,
  0a.stat_value
FROM leaderheadsplayers p
LEFT JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
ON 0a.player_id    = p.player_id
AND 0a.stat_type   = 'kills'
WHERE p.player_id IN
  (SELECT player_id
  FROM
    (SELECT 0a.player_id
    FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_alltime 0a
    WHERE 0a.stat_type = 'kills'
    ORDER BY 0a.stat_value DESC LIMIT 0,
      20
    ) 1a
  )
order by 
  0a.stat_value,  p.player_id;
```

Comment: Won't this hurt the performance if 0a.stat_value is something like a sum or something?

Comment: I actually had to use that redundant subquery level because my MySQL version doesn't allow to use ORDER by in a IN clause. It's kind of a bypass.

Comment: @Robin I see. Does it produce the result as you expect?

Comment: Yes it does. I also had that solution but I was just wondering about the performance but it seems fine.