# php explode array data inserting error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i try to insert array with another string value to database it give Column count doesn't match value count error. My code given bellow any explanation why this error occurring

```
$Skills = "java,php";
$memberId ="1";
$wordArray = explode(",", $Skills);
$query = "INSERT INTO tempskill (skill,memberId) VALUES ('" .implode("'),  ('", $wordArray). "'  , '".$memberId."' ) ";
echo  $Skills;                   

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error :' . mysql_error());
```

this code output is - java,C#Error :Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Print your query by put an echo on $query and run the query on mysql terminal and check the error

Comment: Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
when i echo query it gives this - 
INSERT INTO tempskill (skill,memberId) VALUES ( 'abc'), ('def' , '1' ) Error :Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: MemberID for `abc` is not set. DO you see it?

Comment: Yes when use SQL like this it work 
INSERT INTO tempskill (skill,memberId) VALUES ( 'abc' ,   '1' ), ('def',   '1')

but the problem is how to pass like  this with explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `memberId` to each pair of inserted values you should use:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tempskill (skill,memberId) VALUES ('" .implode("', '" . $memberId . "'),  ('", $wordArray) . "', '" . $memberId . "')";
// echoes `INSERT INTO tempskill (skill,memberId) VALUES ('java', '1'),  ('php', '1')`
```

But

1. `mysql` extension is outdated and **removed** in php7.
2. Such code is vurnerable to sql injections.

So, I advise you to move to `PDO`/`mysqli` apis and prepared statements. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).