# comprae value in JSON_TYPE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a field in my Database table colled `interet`, it has a json array like you see in this picture.
[image]

I want to check if one values or two is IN this fields using Mysql query.
I was trying to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers c WHERE c.interet IN ('Voyage','Technologie','Mode')
```

But I got nothing

Comment: that is not a json_array

Comment: it's not json. looking string or text type data

Comment: What you have in your table is not JSON but simply comma separated values in a column. Which you should not be saving in a column. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41215681/267540 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41305027/267540

Comment: aaah ok so if I make it json array will be worked ?

Comment: not json array but can use like : where c.interet  like '%Voyage%' or c.interet  like '%Technologie%' or c.interet  like '%Mode%'   group by id  <id the primary key of table>

Comment: JSON will only make things marginally better. Please google for database normalization and read the two QAs in my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not json USE like operator

```
    SELECT * FROM customers c WHERE 
    c.interet LIKE '% Voyage %' OR 
    c.interet LIKE '% Technologie %' OR 
    c.interet LIKE '% Mode %'
```

Comment: yes this works and if you have a few hundred thousand rows, make your service unresponsive

Comment: Ya I agree with that

Answer (score 0):

The format above is not json it is a varchar. update your question and post your full sql query