# how to use REGEXP in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column in my table called `to_user` that the content of it like this:

```
id     to_user

1.       1+2+3

2.         1
```

my query

```
select 
 * from notifications 
 where (type = 4 and to_user LIKE %+".$user_id."+%) 
 or (to_user REGEXP +?".$user_id."+? ) and status = 2
```

but it doesn't work .

Comment: Does not make much sense. what is `+?`

Comment: Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Answer (score 1):

you should enclose the strig for search  in proper quotes (and remove + if is not part oth string of you sarch condition )

```
"select * from notifications where (type = 4 and to_user LIKE '%".$user_id."%') 
    or (to_user REGEXP '".$user_id."' ) and status = 2" ;
```

due the fact you are using string if you n need  an exact macth  is =  istead of like  and don't use regex too

Comment: you have a typo ;) please replace ì with '

Comment: I think the plusses are there to prevent users with part of the ids to be selected. if you search for user id `1` now, user id `215` will also be selected.

Comment: @Jerodev   i have added  a brief suggestio for exact match too

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM notifications 
WHERE (type = 4 and to_user 
LIKE '%" . $user_id . "%') 
OR (to_user REGEXP '\+" . $user_id . "\+' ) 
AND status = 2";
```