# How to compare current date with a date range or discrete date values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, date

I am saving multiple dates in database in one column separates by comma(,) like

1. 2017-03-05, 2017-03-06, 2017-03-07, 2017-03-08, 2017-03-08.
2. 2017-03-05, 2017-03-08

I just want to know that how I compare current date by these dates. In the first example, its easy, but problem is for the second one.

Can anyone help me out....?

Thanks...

Comment: Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: This is not how you should be storing your data. Normalize the table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad I'm also not clear how example 1 is easy but 2 is not..

Comment: What exact comparison do you need to make?

Comment: These are batch dates. there are two types batches
1. Weekend Batches (example 1)
2. Daily batches (example 2)
Now I want to create Attendance Module, for that I want to compare current date with these dates. So in first example I can directly compare by using LIKE, but not for second. 
Is there any SQL query for compare current date by these dates?

Comment: I want something like this
1. 2017-03-05,2017-03-06,2017-03-07,2017-03-08,2017-03-08.
2. 2017-03-05,2017-03-08

CURRENT_DATE >= 2017-03-05 AND CURRENT_DATE<=2017-03-08
IN SQL

Comment: So as I understand it there are two cases: If there are exactly two dates, the current date should be tested to see if it falls between the range defined by those dates. Otherwise, the current date should be compared for an exact match against any of the individual dates. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.... This is what I want...

Comment: Then you are asking too much.  Redesign.

Comment: Next you will want a mixture of discrete dates and date ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use `find_in_set()` and `substring_index()`, if I had such a lousy data structure:

```
select t.*
from t
where find_in_set(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d'), datecol) > 0 or
      (datecol like '%,%' and datecol not like '%,%,%' and
       date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d') between substring_index(datecol, ',', 1) and substring_index(datecol, ',', -1)
      );
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented, it would be preferable to normalise the data and store individual dates in multiple rows of a linked table rather than in a single field. But assuming there's a valid reason this can't be done, the following will do what you've asked:

```
SELECT date_csv,
       CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(date_csv, ',', '')) = CHAR_LENGTH(date_csv) - 1
            THEN /* date_csv has a single comma */
                 CURRENT_DATE >= SUBSTRING(date_csv, 1, INSTR(date_csv, ',') - 1)
                 AND CURRENT_DATE <= SUBSTRING(date_csv, INSTR(date_csv, ',') + 1)
            ELSE /* date_csv has either no comma or multiple commas */
                 FIND_IN_SET(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d'), date_csv) > 0
       END AS 'Test result'
```

**Rextester demo:** http://rextester.com/EPKO65812

Comment: Okay... Thanks for your help

Comment: On board with your answer!

Answer (score 2):

> you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to compare `CURRENT_DATE` with your comma separated
>   dates

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(CURRENT_DATE,'2017-03-05,2017-03-06,2017-03-07,2017-03-08,2017-03-08');
```

EDIT

MySQL FIND_IN_SET() returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings, so for your second set it simple returns zero

so you can do some thing like below

```
 SELECT * from tbl where FIND_IN_SET(CURRENT_DATE,'2017-03-05,2017-03-08')>0
```

Comment: I can use the for first example, What for second.

Comment: so are you talking about missing data?

Comment: Not missing data first is weekend batch (date of every days). Second is daily batch (only first and last date)

Comment: @GyandeepSharma Don't do this. Instead, fix your broken schema.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2017-03-08',comma_date );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$string_date='2017-03-05,2017-03-06,2017-03-07,2017-03-08,2017-03-08';
$tmp_dates=explode(',',$string_date);

foreach($tmp_dates as $tmp_date)
{
$newDateString = date_format(date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $tmp_date), 'Y-m-d');

$interval =date_diff(date_create($newDateString),date_create(date('Y-m-d')));
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```