# Insert multiple values of input fields one column in rows in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a form which contains some input fields and checkboxes, I want to insert all the values of input in one column (rows).

Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Built in year</label>
<input name="feature[]">

<label>View</label>
<input name="feature[]">
```

here is my controller:

```
function create_listing(){
        $this->load->view('form');
       if($_POST){

    $feature  = array ( 'feature' => $_POST['feature'] );

                foreach($feature as $fkey => $fvalue ){

                     $this->Mdata->f_detail($fvalue);

                }


        }
```

and here is my model:

```
    function f_detail($fvalue){

             $this->db->insert('feature',$fvalue);
             return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

I am getting an error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2) VALUES ('build in year', 'view', 'parking space')' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO `feature` (0, 1, 2) VALUES ('build in year', 'view', 'parking space')
```

What's wrong in my code. Anyone please tell me .

Regards

Comment: this is not the way you should be using a RDBMS. There are thousands of questions here from people who took this path and are now stuggling
Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: put "echo $this->db->last_query();die;" after your insert query. It will display your query and check where you going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->input->post()` instead of `$_POST()` in `codeigniter` both are equivalent.

**Controller**:

```
function create_listing(){
    if($this->input->post()){
    $feature  = $this->input->post('feature');

    foreach($feature as $fkey => $fvalue ){

     $ids []= $this->Mdata->f_detail($fvalue);//$Ids is array of returned id

    }
    $this->load->view('form');//load view after database operations

}
```

**Model**:

In your model you need to specify `column name` like below:

```
  function f_detail($fvalue)
  {
     $this->db->insert('feature',array('column_name'=>$fvalue));//specify column name
     return $this->db->insert_id();

  }
```

Comment: is there any way if i applied loop in model instead of controller

Comment: yes it is possible.You need to pass feature array `$feature ` then use loop there.

Comment: did you solve it using above answer or any other problem.

Comment: actually my form insert data in two tables, one table is for features and other are basic information ?? this one is working but the problem is my basic information is inserting multiple times. for instance if user check on 3 features the basic information also insert 3 dublicate data.

Comment: so i want user basic information insert one time but this is not happening due to foreach loop

Comment: then take first `feature `using `feature[0]` and insert into first table and take second value using `feature[1]` and insert into second table.No need to use foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can input multiple value into one column with `implode` function.

**Controller**:

```
function create_listing(){
    if($this->input->post()){
        $data = array (
            'feature' => implode(",", $this->input->post('feature'))
        );

        $this->Mdata->f_detail($data);
    }
    else{
        $data = array ();
        $this->load->view('form', $data);    
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
function f_detail($data){
    $this->db->insert('feature',$data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: i want to insert values from 3 fields into a single column in database, can you help me with that?