# How to insert multiple data in a single field in mysql using array or etc. with comma separator

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have file names A, B, C, D then I want to insert them in database in a single field then it will look like this in a table

```
ID | filename  | PATH | DATE         |
1  | A, B, C, D| DOCX | Mar. 10, 2017|
```

Comment: this is not the way you should be using a RDBMS. There are thousands of questions here from people who took this path and are now stuggling
Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: **Never do that.**  See normalization.

Comment: you can also have a look at `serialize` in mysql helps you to keep data in one column

Comment: One option is that use serialize in it and another options make other table for it. Never save data in one column because it rise problem in future.

Comment: you have an array of ABCD value?

Comment: What if we have n number of same data, like here filename might have A,B,C,D,E.....n??

Answer (score 1):

Never put comma separated data like `A, B, C, D` in a single column. Instead use `Normalization`.

Normalization is a database design technique which organizes tables in a manner that reduces redundancy and dependency of data.
It divides larger tables to smaller tables and link them using relationships.

In your case make an another table like `tbl_filenames` and put multiple entries of file name in it and bind it with your base table with \

```
id -> file_id basic
```

means on each entry in base table their are multiple file entry in `tbl_filenames` and bond together user `id->file_id`

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate those & insert like a single value. Its up to you if you wanna do that, But its against normalization & will make system harder to handle, but after all if you insist on doing that:

```
INSERT INTO tblName (`ID`, `filename`, `PATH`, `DATE`) VALUES (1, "A" . ", " . "B" . ", " . "C" . ", " . "D", "DOCX", "Mar. 10, 2017")
```