# check case when in comma seperated values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, case

In my table contain a column marks that value ''Mark 1,Mark 2'.I want to update this column as 1,2.

**Query**

```
   UPDATE dummy  
     SET `mark` =  CASE  
                    WHEN mark= 'Mark 1' THEN '1' 
                    WHEN  mark LIKE '%,Mark 1,Mark 2,%'  THEN '1,2,3' 
                    ELSE mark 
                    END
```

Comment: storing delimited values is not a correct way of storing data in RDBMS. See Normalization.

Comment: this is not the way you should be using a RDBMS. There are thousands of questions here from people who took this path and are now stuggling
Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 UPDATE dummy  
     SET `mark` =  Replace(`mark`,'mark ','')
```