# I want to find word in double quote in database column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find some word on my database column with SQL command

e.g.

```
-------------------
|       tb1       |
|-----------------|
| id              |
| name            |
-------------------
```

Records in name field

```
-> 1st Row "abc","aba","acc","bcc","aaa","bbb"
-> 2nd Row "abc","bcd","efc","aaa","sss","eee"
-> 3rd Row "acc","cdc","ass","qqq","sss","bbb"
```

how to find "acc" and "abc"

Comment: `select * from tb1 where name='acc' or name='abc'`?

Comment: how are these saved in column like `abc` or `"abc"`

Comment: not yet

"abc","aba","acc","bcc","aaa","bbb" same row

Comment: Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681
Don't save CSV in a column Don't save CSV in a column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the rows from which the name field is equal to "acc" and "abc" then write

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE name LIKE '"acc"' OR name LIKE '"abc"';
```

Just in case if you want you can escape the double qoutes with \" not necessary though but this is how it would look like

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE name LIKE '\"acc\"' OR name LIKE '\"abc\"';
```

Or if you want just the name then write

```
SELECT name FROM tb1 WHERE name LIKE '\"acc\"' OR name LIKE '\"abc\"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 where name LIKE '%"abc"%';
```

Put string with double quotes "abc" inside '% .. %'.