# MySql - split record that contains multiple words

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL and everything related to coding, and I need your help!
I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
table1
~~~~~~
id,
question,  
answer, 
keywords.
```

the 'keywords' column contains multiple words with a comma in between(ex: word1, word2, word3, etc...)
and I have a search bot (written in PHP)
whenever the user asks a question (the question should be transformed into an array/keyword) 
then the query should search for the keywords to find the row that contains the most matching keywords and display the answer.

Is there a correct way of doing this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. See normalization.

Comment: The correct way should be to normalize your table.. CSV (comma separated values) are hard to query

Comment: if you want to exact match keyword then it will not wok, otherwise you can use LIKE in query to search

Comment: Don't save CSV in a column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304945/best-type-of-indexing-when-there-is-like-clause/41305027#41305027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry/41215681#41215681

Comment: **Stop! in the name of love, before you break our hearts.**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPBkiBbO4_4  Think it over. Do not do this **a,b,c** data formatting unless some fool has left you this data format. Normalize your data. Add a new table for this one-to-many relationship. Do it now.

Comment: @O.Jones many-to-many relationship! This Song tho :-D :-D

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in MySQL (see [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)) but the best practice and most convenient solution would be normalization, the first form (atomicity) to be exact.

Create a new table, named `keywords` with `keyword_id` (indexed) and `keyword` (unique), add a compound primary key over both fields.

Create another table called `question_has_keywords` with `id` from your main table and `keyword_id`, both Foreign Keys.

This is called a N to M relation table because many questions can have many keywords.

To lookup the data, you would use `JOIN`.

Funfact - This would be such an easy task using MongoDB Aggregation (`$unwind` pipeline stage).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use FIND_IN_SET() function to search keyword in your column separated by comma